# How to properly change this curl to url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

I am trying to make api request and I am getting some error because I miss typed the parameter(I guess). I am very new to curl and I am having hard time interpreting it. I have look all over the place for tutorial on curl yet I have not been successful.

Here is the curl

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/44322889'
```

here is the url I came up with which returned no client id

```
url = https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/44322889/Client-id=uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2/accept=application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json
```

can anyone help me what I have missed?

Comment: Hi Olivia. You need specify key value pairs in your url, query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It uses the url query parameters scheme. `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/4432288?client_id=uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2`

Comment: I just checked the twitch docs. Client ids are supposed to be specified as `client_id`.

Comment: still not working you can copy paste it on your browser and see for your self why it is not working

Comment: Well I am getting a bad client_id so i'm not sure if you've supplied the right one. But also `-h` is a header parameter and you cannot send that in a `GET` request without using server side logic or postman. Try the revised url above and let me know what response you get.